# Expecting authentication method via either a service token, --os-token

Tags: 12.04, openstack

I have OpenStack installed. When I try to execute this command

```
keystone user-list
```

I get this

```
  Expecting authentication method via
  either a service token, --os-token or env[OS_SERVICE_TOKEN], 
  or credentials, --os-username or env[OS_USERNAME].
```

How do I specify a token?

Comment: I said I am a beginner. I did not specified anything... please tell me how do I specify?

Comment: How did you install openstack?

Comment: By following this
http://ilearnstack.com/2013/04/26/setting-up-a-single-node-openstack-environment/

Comment: @UmairAyub Updating your question with how you installed OpenStack gives a better change that another reader might pick up your question. Comments are not so often read.

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide below parameter or export it from command line:

```
export OS_SERVICE_TOKEN=************************
export OS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT=http://controller.domain.com:35357/v2.0
```

The token must be same as that of you have in `keystone.conf` file with parameter name `admin_token = ************************`. Probably you will have one at path `/etc/keystone/keystone.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

For **Havana setup** the name of environment variable changes.

I got following error **while creating tenant** before creating any of the auth user:-

```
  Expecting authentication method via
  either a service token, --os-token or env[SERVICE_TOKEN], 
  or credentials, --os-username or env[SERVICE_ENDPOINT].
```

For resolving this issue with Havana setup, you have to

```
# export SERVICE_TOKEN=123456
# export SERVICE_ENDPOINT=http://controller:35357/v2.0
```

**Just omit the "OS_" prefix here.**

I was referring the Official guide of Havana setup Available http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/apt/openstack-install-guide-apt-havana.pdf